# Create unique list of names

Tags: r, igraph

I have a list of actors:

```
name <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
age <- c(26 , 32, 56)
postcode <- c('4011', '5600', '7700')
actors <- data.frame(name, age, postcode)

        name age postcode
1   John Doe  26     4011
2 Peter Gynn  32     5600
3 Jolie Hope  56     7700
```

I also have an edge list of relations:

```
from <- c('John Doe','John Doe','John Doe', 'Peter Gynn', 'Peter Gynn', 'Jolie Hope')
to <- c('John Doe', 'John Doe', 'Peter Gynn', 'Jolie Hope', 'Peter Gynn', 'Frank Smith')
edge <- data.frame(from, to)

        from          to
1   John Doe    John Doe
2   John Doe    John Doe
3   John Doe  Peter Gynn
4 Peter Gynn  Jolie Hope
5 Peter Gynn  Peter Gynn
6 Jolie Hope Frank Smith
```

First, I want to eliminate self references in my edge list i.e. rows 1,2,5 in my 'edge' dataframe.

```
non.self.ref <- edge[!(edge$from == edge$to),]
```

does not produce the desired result.

Second, edge includes a name not in the 'actor' dataframe ('Frank Smith'). I want to add 'Frank Smith' to my 'actor' dataframe, even though I do not have age or postcode data for 'Frank Smith'. For example:

```
         name age postcode
1    John Doe  26     4011
2  Peter Gynn  32     5600
3  Jolie Hope  56     7700
4 Frank Smith  NA       NA
```

I would be grateful for a tidy solution!

Comment: I managed to solve my first question. edge <- data.frame(from, to, stringsAsFactors = F)

Comment: Just `edge[edge$from != edge$to,]` would do it too once you remove the factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution to both parts, though in general try not to ask multiple questions per question.

1. The first part is fairly simple. `filter` allows a very intuitive syntax that just specifies you want to keep rows where `from` isn't equal to `to`.
2. The second part is a little more complicated. First we `gather` up the `from` and `to` columns, so all the actors are in one column. Then we use `distinct` to leave us with a one column tbl with unique actor names. Finally, we can use `full_join` to combine the tables. A `full_join` keeps all rows and columns from both tables, matching on shared name column by default, and fills `NA` if there is no data (as there isn't for Frank).

```r
library(tidyverse)
actors <- tibble(
  name = c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope'),
  age = c(26 , 32, 56),
  postcode = c('4011', '5600', '7700')
  )
edge <- tibble(
  from = c('John Doe','John Doe','John Doe', 'Peter Gynn', 'Peter Gynn', 'Jolie Hope'),
  to = c('John Doe', 'John Doe', 'Peter Gynn', 'Jolie Hope', 'Peter Gynn', 'Frank Smith')
)

edge %>%
  filter(from != to)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   from       to         
#>   <chr>      <chr>      
#> 1 John Doe   Peter Gynn 
#> 2 Peter Gynn Jolie Hope 
#> 3 Jolie Hope Frank Smith

edge %>%
  gather("to_from", "name", from, to) %>%
  distinct(name) %>%
  full_join(actors)
#> Joining, by = "name"
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   name          age postcode
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>   
#> 1 John Doe     26.0 4011    
#> 2 Peter Gynn   32.0 5600    
#> 3 Jolie Hope   56.0 7700    
#> 4 Frank Smith  NA   <NA>
```

Created on 2018-03-02 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered by including `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` e.g.

```
edge <- data.frame(from, to, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

then:

```
non.self.ref <- edge[!(edge$from == edge$to),]
```

works!

Comment: Glad you got base R to work! stringsAsFactors is one of the major problem points with `data.frame` and which `tibble` helps to avoid

Answer (score 0):

An option with `dplyr` would be to `filter` the rows by comparing 'from' and 'to' (to get the first output - it is not needed if we are interested only at the second output), `unlist`, get the `unique` values, convert it to a `tibble` and do a `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
edge %>%
  filter(from != to) %>% #get the results for the first question
  unlist %>%
  unique %>% 
  tibble(name = .) %>% 
  left_join(actors) # second output
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#   name          age postcode
#   <chr>       <dbl> <fctr>  
#1 John Doe     26.0 4011    
#2 Peter Gynn   32.0 5600    
#3 Jolie Hope   56.0 7700    
#4 Frank Smith  NA   <NA>
```